# Moving image in CSS- freecodecamp product landing project

Tags: html, css, image, position

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to move the images in card  ( the three little icons) so they are just in front of the h1 items in the same div?

Here is the link to my project:

```
[codepen] https://codepen.io/theone2/pen/WNZeJOR
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure ? ( allowed to ? )   then you can easily ' move ' them where you want

Comment: @Mihai T If by that you mean to put the <img> before <h1> in html, i've tried that, but it's still not allowing me( or i don't know how) to put the icon just in front of the h1, like here https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/RKRbwL

Comment: Well you already have an example on how to do it. With HTML and CSS code at your disposal. Why don't you use that example and apply it to yours ? Just use grid or flexbox to have 2 columns. 1st with image second with title and description. Like in the example

Comment: As the little images are purely a visual clue, not part of the meaning (e.g. of no interest to screen readers), consider adding them in pseudo elements to those elements.